# Finding subarray whose xor is 0

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor, trie, bitwise-xor

I'm stuck at one problem i.e. to find a subarray whose xor is 0.
I read somewhere that this can be done using TRIE data structure but I want the starting and ending indices of the array.

For example, consider an array

a = [3, 6, 13, 8 15]

The subarray from 0 to 3 i.e. [3, 6, 13, 8] has xor equal to 0.
(3 xor 6 xor 13 xor 8 = 0)
I'm in search for an algorithm than can find those indices ([0, 3] in this case).

Detailed answer would be very helpful.

**Update**
I tried the brute Force approach find checking xor for all pairs of [i, j]. This gives TLE since the no. of elements in the array could be upto 10^5

The I tried a solution mentioned [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-subarrays-given-xor/) but this doesn't give indices.

I'm looking for an algorithm with O(nLogn) or possibly O(n) complexity.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: And also *trie* is not the only solution. There might be several solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution take `O(n)` complexity also. Take the benefit of [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/).

```
vector<int> a = {3,6,13,8,15};
unordered_map<int, int> hashMap;
int number_of_elements = a.size();
hashMap[0] = -1;
int xor_sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++) {
    xor_sum ^= a[i];
    if(hashMap.find(xorSum) != hashMap.end()) {
        cout << hashMap[xorSum] + 1 << " " << i << endl;
        break;
    }
    hashMap[xor_sum] = i;
}
```

Comment: I think this will assumes that a[0] will be included in the sub-array.

Comment: I will try to remember that if I have seen a value to the prefix. If I see this value then xor sum of starting from the that index + 1 and end with current index will be 0.

Comment: @Faruk Hossain is there any way to modify this algorithm so that it gives all possible subarrays with xor sum 0? I tried removing the break from the loop, but it doesn't include all of them.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Compute XOR of every prefix of the array. I'll call the XOR of the first `i` elements `prefix[i]`. XOR of a subarray `[i, j]` is `prefix[j] ^ prefix[i - 1]`. `prefix[j] ^ prefix[i - 1] == 0 -> prefix[j] == prefix[i - 1]`, so two equal `prefix` values represents an subarray with XOR 0.

Comment: @glitterfarr1337 if you need just one subarray, above answer will work. For all subarrays, head over here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57365476/8596503 It's still not O(n) solution, but the best I've found so far.